# Как в убрать все из текста и оставить только ссылку

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Первый пример:

```
<br>
Сайт компании: [www.al.ru][1]<br><br>Е-mail отдела ронирования:<br><br>tag1@mil.ru<br>tag@mil.ru<br>tag5@mil.ru
```

Второй пример:

```
<br>Е-mail отдела ронирования:<br><br>tag1@mil.ru<br>tag@mil.ru<br>tag5@mil.ru<br><br>Наш сайт - http://www.al.com<br><br>
```

Третий пример:

```
<br>Сайт alllp.net<br><br><br>Е-mail отдела ронирования:<br><br>tag1@mil.ru<br>tag@mil.ru<br>tag5@mil.ru<br>
```

и т.д. (могут встречаться и другие ненужные символы, теги (к прим. типа br))

```
<br><br>
Любой пример закидываем в переменную %text<br>
```

Ответ желателен в виде:

```
<br>
Текст:`%text`<br> 
найти что:<br>
заменить на что:<br>
```

Остаться должны ссылки ввида:

```
<br>
al.ru<br>
alllp.net<br>
al.com<br>
```

Comment: Что вы уже сделали? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: для общего случая - регулярку нельзя написать

Comment: Погуглите, например, регулярку для корректного e-mail адреса. Это весьма нетривиально. Для корректного доменного имени это проще, конечно, но, думаю, в результате получится строчек 30 (минимум) текста.

Comment: Вот пытаюсь начать изучать регулярные. Начала с конструктора http://www.pcre.ru/eval/   вот стопорюсь: ([a-z]+.+.)

Comment: Как задачу массово решить уже примерно знаю. Но это не при помощи регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

Посмотрите ссылку http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=391&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Там хорошо написано про ограничения, которым соответствует эта регулярка. На самом деле, она тоже не вполне корректна (не промеряется макимальная длина 253 символа).

Еще раз повторюсь, корректная регулярка для e-mail занимает страницу(!) текста: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

P.S. Не понимаю, за что Вам накидали минусов.

P.P.S. Необходимо понимать, что в тексте может встретиться нечто, выглядещее как корректный адрес, но таковым не являющееся (например пропущенный пробел между фразами). Кроме того, эта регулярка не поймет кириллические адреса сайтов, типа `кремль.рф`.

Comment: Плиз, кто-нибудь, напишите, где я ошибся в слове `выглядещее`. Режет глаз, но не пойму, в чем дело)

Comment: Так мне не e-mail-ы нужны.) Мне оставить только гиперссылки

Comment: @Анна, думаю, Вам подойдет эта регулярка. Она довольно проста и понятна, и в целом опознает почти все как надо. Для кириллических доменов, опять же, несложно доработать. `^` и `$` в начале и конце, для Ваших целей, конечно, не нужны.

Comment: @andy.37 Правильно - "выглядящее". http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5